# react production build 404 not found

Tags: apache, reactjs

Hello i need to deploy react app.

To achieve that i run : "npm run build"

after that in my vhost.conf i've added vhost

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName hello.local
DocumentRoot c:/wamp64/www/hello_world/build
<Directory  "c:/wamp64/www/hello_world/build">
             Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
             AllowOverride All
             Require all granted
</Directory>
```

i've also added to etc/hosts hello.local

of course i've enabled mod rewrite in httpd.conf

When i run hello.local/ main page of my react app display properly, but when i want to go to react-react route path hello.local/example i received 404 not found error. Please help what can it be ? It's problem with apache configuration or react-router has some mistake ? Regards

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is a common issue that comes up for SPA. In SPA, mostly the routing happens on client side. In your case, mostly `react-router` should be doing the job. Since the whole js is bundled as a single file and is served in `index.html`, you need to serve `index.html` for all paths that is `non-existing` in your server.

You have to add a config like this

```
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^ /index.html [L]
```

So, if there is no matching path in your server, the index.html would get served. Then the javascript would execute and `react-router`(client side routing) will take over and display the correct component for the route.

This is true for most SPA, where the routing happens on client side.

Comment: Yes sir, i've done it in this way, but it's one of the best explained answer :) kudos for you !  @Panther What is SPA ?
Here is reference how to deploy on production: https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#deployment

Comment: You are soooo awesome!!!!!!! Forgot about the .htaccess file to place in root. Now everything is working :)

Comment: thats exactly what I was looking for! Thank you very much after 5 days of research! Although still have a problem with paths to image assets when my route takes more than one parameter, f.i. /test/id then it looks for a path in /test/assets/img... which is giving 404

Comment: How can I return a 404 HTTP status code for a route which does not exist using a SPA? E.g., if I serve everything `index.html` for all paths that do not exist on my server, e.g. `/path/which/does/not/exists/123`, I cannot tell the client that `/path/which/does/not/exists/123` does not exist with a 404 response code if I have served `index.html` with a 200 response code. How can I deal with this? Am I forced to use another hybrid strategy and use isomorphic `React` with `Server-Side Rendering` or is there a way to do that with classic SPAs?

Comment: In a SPA, the routes are known to the client side code. The server will not know the list of all available routes. So the logic to show the 404 should also be on the route side. Since its a SPA and you need to render from server, then it should be done via server side rendering.

Comment: hi @Panther and thanke you for this answer , but where i should add this config any file

Answer (score 0):

Using **web.config** for IIS Window 10

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^" ignoreCase="false" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
        <add input="{DOCUMENT_ROOT}{URL}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" />
        <add input="{DOCUMENT_ROOT}{URL}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="None" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="Imported Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^" ignoreCase="false" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.html" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1" executionTimeout="240" maxRequestLength="2048000" />
    <trace enabled="true" requestLimit="40" localOnly="false" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <defaultDocument>
      <files>
        <clear />
        <add value="Index.aspx" />
        <add value="Default.htm" />
        <add value="Default.asp" />
        <add value="index.htm" />
        <add value="index.html" />
        <add value="iisstart.htm" />
        <add value="default.aspx" />
      </files>
    </defaultDocument>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="false" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```