# React doesn't load page on reload

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I found a similar question here but I did't find an explenation exactly how to fix the problem. All pages on my website except index.html doesn't load when you are reloading the page. From the previousquestion I think that to solve the problem without server I need to use HashHistory but I cant' found explination how to use it. What to do in my app and what to put in my navigation. http://turbo-remont.com/
I made this website for a friend but I can't deal with this problem. Please help me.

Comment: Do you get any error in the console? There's not enough info for helping you I fear

Comment: Possible duplicate of [react production build 404 not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46941278/react-production-build-404-not-found)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your server attempts to fetch the resource and not load the main file (`index.htm`) and then activate navigation.

and example:

Your site base is http://turbo-remont.com, if you navigate to it, your app loads and from that point on overtakes the navigation so if you go to http://turbo-remont.com/resource/1234 , it won't send a new fetch request but internally update the state and load the relevant component (as [SPAs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn463786.aspx) [do](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application)).

When you reload the page, which is actually equivalent to navigating to the page, your server attempts to find and html file named '/resource/1234'. To overcome this, you need to instruct your server to serve index.html regardless of the full url.

I don't know what server you use, but here is a simple example of an `.htaccess` file that solves the problem, place it in your root directory.

`RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]`

Comment: I don't have a server

Comment: So where do you server the files from? Is it the react script? Do you host them somewhere?